# mcrypt_decrypt doesn't work after encrypt - special character issue

Tags: php, mcrypt

I use below code to encrypt and decrypt data:

```
public function encrypt($plaintext) {        
    $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(self::CIPHER, self::MODE);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(self::CIPHER, $this->key, $plaintext, self::MODE, $iv);                
    return base64_encode($iv.$ciphertext);
}

public function decrypt($ciphertext) {
    $ciphertext = base64_decode($ciphertext);
    $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(self::CIPHER, self::MODE);
    if (strlen($ciphertext) < $ivSize) {
        throw new Exception('Missing initialization vector');
    }

    $iv = substr($ciphertext, 0, $ivSize);
    $ciphertext = substr($ciphertext, $ivSize);
    $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(self::CIPHER, $this->key, $ciphertext, self::MODE, $iv);
    return rtrim($plaintext, "\0");
}
```

If I encrypt and descrypt data in same server then it works properly but lets say encryption is happening from server 1 and server 2 gets request for decryption. Decrypted data doesn't look proper. I see some special characters after decryption. something like - ��JL!��2.  Both servers use same code and key for encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: Make sure your data is generated, sent and received in the same format (utf8 for example). In the server 2, how do you get the data from the server 1 ?

Comment: It's api call with post method from sever 1 to server 2